# Parallel execution of different DbContexts is slower than nonparallel version

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, task-parallel-library

I have a simple table with 2 columns (one is `identity` and the other is some `char` column):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl]
(
    [id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col] [CHAR](32) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
```

We have a function that performs some long running actions. Here is some pseudo code:

```
void doWork()
{
    using(context)
    {
        doLongPart1(context);
        ...
        doLongPartN(context);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to isolate those in separate tasks using each own context. But surprisingly version with tasks take more time then without tasks. I am inserting `10,000` rows here. And times are: `~54000ms` for version without tasks and `~57000ms` with tasks. I am using `EF6.0` and here is the complete code to reproduce:

**Initial version**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var c = 10000;

    var c1 = new TestEntities();
    for (int i = 1; i < c / 2; i++)
        c1.tbls.Add(new tbl { col = i.ToString() });

    c1.SaveChanges();

    var c2 = new TestEntities();
    for (int i = c / 2; i < c; i++)
        c2.tbls.Add(new tbl { col = i.ToString() });

    c2.SaveChanges();

    stopwatch.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Version with tasks**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var c = 10000;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[2];

    tasks[0] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var c1 = new TestEntities();

        for (int i = 1; i < c / 2; i++)
            c1.tbls.Add(new tbl { col = i.ToString() });
        c1.SaveChanges();
    });

    tasks[1] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var c2 = new TestEntities();

        for (int i = c / 2; i < c; i++)
            c2.tbls.Add(new tbl { col = i.ToString() });
        c2.SaveChanges();
    });

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have also tried to do this through a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC spTbl @s CHAR(32)
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl (col)
    VALUES (@s)
```

and code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var c = 10000; 
    Task[] tasks = new Task[2];

    tasks[0] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var c1 = new TestEntities();

        for (int i = 1; i < c / 2; i++)
            c1.spTbl(i.ToString());
    });

    tasks[1] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var c2 = new TestEntities();

        for (int i = c / 2; i < c; i++)
            c2.spTbl(i.ToString());
    });

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

I have even tried to configure SQL Server:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 8;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
```

But nothing works for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Most likely the overhead of connecting to the database and/or locks on the table has to do with this.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I am checking this right now with DBA and will let yuo know soon. I will check for selects too. Shouldn't selects give me a difference?

Comment: Ok, as it turns out I've just hit the maximum of my Sql engine, so there was no difference in parallel execution. Both were working with maximum possible speed. Also there was no locks at all at database level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a c# program will not make your database faster.

If your problem is the speed of your insert operation in the database then making it parallel won't lift your bottleneck, it still will be the insert operation on your database.

What you can look at generally are two (3) things

1) Faster drives/SSD (and or more ram) in your database server

2) Reduce the number of indexes since these all have to be updated too on an insert operation

For some operations you can even drop the index, insert all the data you need, and then recreate the index since your index will only be updated once instead on every time you insert a row

**Update:** now i look at your numbers more detailed, 1000 queries/second is not uncommon in applications i've seen.

**Update 2:** One possible solution you might look at is bulk insert https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/ since even with your stored procedure your overhead is in the number of queries and not in the query (assuming you don't have indexes & computed columns)

Comment: Now I have realized that you was actually correct. I hit the limit and parallelism gave me nothing in this case. This is jus a test but in really situation it should give me the benefit, because there are inserts selects, calculations, detetes etc.